# Scrapy : XPath error: Invalid expression in //media:content

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to extract content from a News Site RSS Feed with Item like below

```
<item>
<title>BPS: Kartu Bansos Bantu Turunkan Angka Gini Ratio</title>
<media:content url="/image.jpg" expression="full" type="image/jpeg"/>  </item>
```

but Error  raised When parsing the information with tag like media:content using the xpath like  **item.xpath('//media:content')**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 183, in xpath
    six.reraise(ValueError, ValueError(msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/parsel/selector.py", line 179, in xpath
    smart_strings=self._lxml_smart_strings)
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 1587, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:57923)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__ (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:167084)
  File "src/lxml/xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:166043)
ValueError: XPath error: Undefined namespace prefix in //media:content
```

Does anybody know what should I do? Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell xpath which namespace the `media` prefix is mapped to by calling the [`register_namespace(prefix, namespace)`](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#parsel.selector.Selector.register_namespace) on the selector first, e.g:

```
selector.register_namespace('media', 'http://the.namespace.of/media')
```

or if you only want to use the local name, you can use:

```
 item.xpath("//*[local-name()='content']")
```

Comment: Scrapy selector's `.xpath()` does not accept `namespaces` argument like `lxml` does (but there's [an open PR](https://github.com/scrapy/parsel/pull/45) on this). One has to call [`.register_namespace(prefix, namespace)`](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#parsel.selector.Selector.register_namespace) on the selector beforehand.

Comment: @paultrmbrth thx, I didn't realise this wasn't lxml's xpath(), should have looked closer at the stack trace... thanks for the reference, I've corrected my answer